# Is it right to say available valuable?

Tags: verb-agreement

This sentence is pat from my paper which I would like to submit but I am not sure if it is right?
Does it sound correct?

Is available here correct?

> This study reveals that S and A have complementary performances and 
>                that there are available valuable satellite observed SSM data records over 
>                 more than 5 years, which can be used to study land-atmosphere processes.

Comment: First, put in a hyphen to make it more comprehensible. Second, "available valuable satellite-observed SSM data records" has six words modifying a noun. It's grammatical, but it would sound better with fewer modifiers.

Comment: Thanks Peter,  How would you rewrite it?

Comment: You can get it down to three modifying words with "and that more than 5 years of valuable SSM data records observed from satellites are available". (Although note that it's not really necessary to shorten it that much.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripping out the bare bones,

> Valuable data is available [which will aid in these studies].

may certainly be reformulated:

> There is available valuable data which will aid in these studies.

(Using an existential-there (cleft) construction for 'There is available valuable data.' on its own sounds rather unidiomatic, contrived. I've had to include *a bit* of flesh on the bones, to ensure it sounds merely formal.)

Notice that this is not a pair of attributive adjectives (as in 'a *little brown* dog', or 'there is some *[readily] available* and *valuable* data').

Answer (score 0):

Building on @EdwinAshworth's answer, have you considered:

> Valuable data which will aid in these studies is available.